# When creating a WordPress site how can you create different versions of the site with different themes?

Tags: themes

I want to create different versions of the site with different themes to show a client.  How can I save different versions?  I know about multi-site.

I don't want to do this on the fly.  I want to save different versions so that the client can play around with it.

This is not about Wordpress versions.  I just want to use different themes with the same code.

Comment: Hi, Are you talking about a demo-stuff kind of thing? If so, you need multiple installations to do this. You can do it on a single installation on the fly, but be prepared for theme-dependent issues.

Comment: @JackJohansson Yes.  I want to create demo versions for the client.  Content is the same.  Theme is different.

Comment: The title (the question in it, as well the question itself) is very 'clowdy/misleading' it seems, you are totally not clear about what you want imho. *Different versions*: as in *different WordPress versions* or as in *different Theme versions* or as in *different Themes*? What is it you want? Make yourself/the question more clear about what you want to know so an answer will be easier to be formulated and to the point without the need of several comments to enlighten what you really want to know/to be answered.

Answer (score 0):

If all versions of the theme are uploaded to WordPress wouldn't Live Preview in Appearance –> Themes be an option? Of course it will require anyone who needs to review the themes to login to WordPress but if needed there are user management plugins that could temporarily be used to limit their access.